# Weighted mean of a group, where weight is from another group

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose you have a long data.frame of the following form:

```
ID Group Year Field VALUE
1  1     2016 AA    10
2  1     2016 AA    16
1  1     2016 TOTAL 100
2  1     2016 TOTAL 120
etc..
```

and you want to create an grouped output of `weighted.mean(Value,??)` for each `group_by(Group, Year, Field)` using `Field == TOTAL` as the weight for years >2013.

So far i am using dplyr:

```
dat %>% 
filter(Year>2013) %>% 
group_by(Group, Year, Field) %>% 
summarize(m = weighted.mean(VALUE,VALUE[Field == 'TOTAL'])) %>%
ungroup()
```

Now the problem (to my understanding) is that by using `group_by` I cannot define the "Field" value afterwards, as I tell it to look at the group of "Field == AA".

Transforming data from long to wide is not a solution, as i have >1000 different field values which potentially increase over time, and this code will be run daily at some point.

Comment: Why not just add another row with the values of `VALUE` where `Field == TOTAL`? Then reference this in your call to `weighted.mean()`.

Comment: Great idea. How would you duplicate the value across all "Field"-values ensuring that they are duplicated correctly within each "Year"?

Comment: I'm working on that approach now. As an alternative, is it possible to use the maximum value of `VALUE` instead of where `Field == TOTAL`? Assuming the total value will always be the largest `VALUE` within each Year and Field.

Comment: Unfortunately it is on financial reports. Therefor, to reach the variable TOTAL subtractions happens along the way - so i cannot be 100% that TOTAL is the largest value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this is a hacky solution, and I am sure there is a better approach to this issue. The goal is to make a new column containing the weights, and this approach does so using the filling nature of `left_join()`, but I am sure you could do this with `fill()` or `across()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 4.0.3
# Example data from OP
dat <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,1,2), Group = rep(1,4), Year = rep(2016,4),Field = c("AA","AA","TOTAL","TOTAL"), VALUE = c(10,16,100,120))

# Make a new dataframe containing the TOTAL values
weights <- dat %>% filter(Field == "TOTAL") %>% mutate(w = VALUE) %>% select(-Field,-VALUE)
weights
#>   ID Group Year   w
#> 1  1     1 2016 100
#> 2  2     1 2016 120

# Make a new frame containing the original values and the weights
new_dat <- left_join(dat,weights, by = c("Group","Year","ID"))

# Add a column for weight
new_dat %>% 
  filter(Year>2013) %>% 
  group_by(Group, Year, Field) %>% 
  summarize(m = weighted.mean(VALUE,w)) %>%
  ungroup() 
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'Group', 'Year' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   Group  Year Field     m
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1     1  2016 AA     13.3
#> 2     1  2016 TOTAL 111.
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>